# How to fix 504 nginx gateway timeout in rails production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am facing the nginx gateway timeout in rails server.When we restart the rails server then ,it is working for sometime and after sometime it shows 504 gateway timeout.I have also increased the timeout on nginx.config ,but it is not working .Please help !!

Nginx.config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        client_max_body_size 250M;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: 

POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 

application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 

text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

site-enabled/default

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
#upstream rails_app {
#  server app:3000;
#}

upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/var/www/bleat_server/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
  # server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
         # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/bleat_server/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#       index index.html;

        server_name 35.224.174.127;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
          }

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

#       location / {
#           try_files $uri @app;
#       }

        location @app {
#           proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }

                                                                                                                                   58,1-8        41%
 client_max_body_size 10M;
        keepalive_timeout 10;

        #location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #}
#       location / {
#        proxy_pass http://app;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#        proxy_redirect off;
#   }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

nginx/error.log

```
2021/07/12 05:15:01 [error] 75827#75827: *1651 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.76.253.232, server: admin.bleatfleet.com, request: "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in", host: "admin.bleatfleet.com", referrer: "http://admin.bleatfleet.com/users/sign_up"

2021/07/12 07:18:17 [crit] 75827#75827: *1696 connect() to unix:/var/www/bleat_server/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.241.219.165, server: 35.224.174.127, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/bleat_server/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/", host: "35.224.174.127"
```

Comment: how are you accessing the prod server, means domain?

Comment: Are you sure that the timeout is caused by Nginx, and not the upstream itself? Do you have metrics/logs for the upstream?

Comment: it is upstream time out